# How to parse and use lines from a text file in C#

Tags: c#

So I am trying to create a Windows Form program. The program is supposed to use a menustrip to open a handful of various text files containing lines of text for a student name, class, and a series of grades. The program then adds the name/class to labels on the form, and adds the grades to an array which is then used to calculate a final score. I managed to get the program to let me open the text file. I was then able to put all the information into a richtextbox.

However, now I am trying to parse out the lines and make use of them. I'm trying to divide the lines up into variables and split them where there is a comma.

I tried using the string[] textSplit = OpenFile.Split(","); but I get an error.

How can I split up the pieces of text and then how can I actually interact with each line? What should I be doing next? I'm so lost.

```
   private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog
        {
            InitialDirectory = @"",
            Title = "Browse Text Files",

            CheckFileExists = true,
            CheckPathExists = true,

            DefaultExt = "txt",
            Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt",
            FilterIndex = 2,
            RestoreDirectory = true,

            ReadOnlyChecked = true,
            ShowReadOnly = true
        };

        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            
        }

        var OpenFile = new System.IO.StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName);
        richTextBox1.Text = OpenFile.ReadToEnd();
        string[] textSplit = OpenFile.Split(",");


    }
```

Comment: Are you trying to split the text which was returned from `OpenFile.ReadToEnd()`? You're trying to call `Split` on the `StreamReader`, rather than the string returned by `ReadToEnd()`

Answer (score 3):

The following logic might be helpful in a way you could go about actually interact with each line:

```
//read all lines of the file into an array

//foreach string in the array

  //split the line on comma and store in an array X
```

Then you can access specific words of that line using indexes

Answer (score 0):

the `openFile` variable contains the stream of the file you're opening, You must split the text in RichTextBox. I suggest that you use `using` block to read the file, and then read file contents.

I have edited my answer, but in this cases you have to Model your data in a class, for example a `Student` class that defines your data model containing student's name, class, grades, etc. And then populate it when reading the file line by line.

To open the file using `OpenFileDialog`:

```
private string openFile() {
            using(var openFileDlg = new OpenFileDialog()) {
                openFileDlg.DefaultExt = "txt";
                openFileDlg.Filter = "txt files(*.txt)| *.txt";
                if(openFileDlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
                    return openFileDlg.FileName;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Then you read the file by passing `filename` you've got from above method to it.

```
private void readFile(string filename) {
            string result = "";
            using (var OpenFile = new System.IO.StreamReader(filename)) {
                result = OpenFile.ReadToEnd();
            }

            richTextBox1.Text = result; //Show the whole content in RichTextBox

            using(var reader = new StringReader(result)) {
                string line = string.Empty;
                do {
                    line = reader.ReadLine();
                    if (line != null) {
                        var data = line.Split(',');
                        //You can now assing each value
                        var name = data[0]; //Suppose that the first one is Student's name
                        var className = data[1];
                        //Assign other data
                    }

                } while (line != null);
            }
        }
```

In the `do` loop, when the line is not null, you can create a new instance of `Student` class and assign the values to properties. It would be much cleaner.

Comment: This seems incorrect, canton's comment or the other answer is far better. However the suggestion to add the using, to free resources are read, is fine. Why would you add an array of strings to a Textbox's text property, the output would just something like "System.String[]"?

Comment: @DanielD it's not the best answer but I did NOT assign array to `Text` property of `RichTextBox`, the `result` is assigned to it.

Comment: well, now that you've edited your answer it looks better and no longer outputs the array type. Also you don't have to create and use a class if you don't want to, it's just a suggestion to make things more clear. A filled array or single variables, like posted in your answer, are also fine.

Comment: @DanielD Good to know your comment on this but not relevant. As I've said before and you can see for yourself in revisions, I did not assign array to `RichTextBox` :)))

Answer (score 0):

I suggest *extracting methods* we can decompose the initial problem into *easier* one's. First, let's ask for the file name (`null` if the file is not provided):

```
 public static string ConfigFileName() {
   using (OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog() {
        InitialDirectory = @"",
        Title = "Browse Text Files",

        CheckFileExists = true,
        CheckPathExists = true,

        DefaultExt = "txt",
        Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt",
        FilterIndex = 2,
        RestoreDirectory = true,

        ReadOnlyChecked = true,
        ShowReadOnly = true  
     }) {

     // We return file name if and only if OK pressed
     return openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK
       ? openFileDialog1.FileName
       : null;  
   }
 }
```

Then let's *query* the file data: we'll read file lines and split eachline into items. We can do it with a help of *Linq*

```
 private static string[] ConfigRecords() {
   string fileName = ConfigFileName();

   if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fileName))
     return new string[0];

   return File
     .ReadLines(fileName)
     .Where(line => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line)) // no empty lines
     .SelectMany(line => line.Split(
        new char[] { ',', ';', '\t'}, //TODO: think over delimiters
        StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
     .Select(item => item.Trim()) // let's be nice and trim spaces
     .Where(item => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item)) // no empty items  
     .Distinct(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) // remove duplicates if any
     .OrderBy(item => item, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
     .ToArray();
 }
```

Finally, you can use the methods in the UI:

```
 private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   string[] records = ConfigRecords();

   richTextBox1.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, records);
 }
```